# sublime snippet for jquery ajax not rendering

Tags: jquery, ajax, sublimetext, code-snippets, sublimetext3

Trying to figure out why this sublime text snippet won't render from the keyboard shortcut:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
var url = '';

var jqxhr = $.ajax(url)
    .done(function() {
        console.log('success');
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log('error');
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log('complete');
    });
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>jsajax</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

If I edit it down to a simple url variable, it will render fine, so I'm guessing there's something invalid in the ajax request, but I can't figure out why. I'm using sublime text 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the dollar sign: `\$`

Comment: This is incredible...!! :)